# PGP keys on Android

Tags: security

How do I set up a PGP key on my Samsung Android 4.1.1 tablet? No idea what I'm doing so please give step by step simplistic instructions

Comment: Maybe we should take a step back and ask: why do you think you need this? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

There are some apps for PGP on Android:

- [OpenKeychain](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.sufficientlysecure.keychain)
- [AGP](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.thialfihar.android.apg)